# VB.NET Set default's printer orientation

Tags: vb.net, printing

Is there a way for me to change the printer orientation of the default printer with VB 2010 just like you would normally change it from Printers and Devices and entering the printer preferences?

```
    Try
        Dim MyProcess As New Process
        MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
        MyProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "print"
        MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "outputvb.pdf"
        MyProcess.Start()
        MyProcess.WaitForExit(2000)
        Try
            MyProcess.CloseMainWindow()
            MyProcess.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

**UPDATE:**
Check the old post, are you able to advice me a better solution then exporting the reportviewer to a PDF then printing the PDF from Visual Basic?

Basically what I want to really do is take load the reportviewer with data and after it loads print it automatically without pressing any buttons to the default printer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've ended up going with was turning the report I had into a TIF file and printing the TIF file from the Windows API (which is 20x faster on a normal PC).

Thank you all for your suggestions even tough none was used.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do it. Page settings or printer.

Using the example from [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.compatibility.vb6.printer.orientation.aspx)

```
 Dim Printer As New Printer
 Printer.Orientation = vbPRORLandscape
```

Or you can use page settings. Again, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.landscape(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
        Dim pd As New PrintDocument()
         pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer
        ' Set the page orientation to landscape.
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        pd.Print()
```

**UPDATE:**

So I see that you are using a process to print instead of printer or a print doc (some don't like adobe reader in particular, [here's](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?662405-RESOLVED-Printing-PDF-Files) a forum why). I wouldn't do that if I were you (why not use a already well support printerdoc api?), but that's your question and I'll try to answer it.

The answer is **it depends**. You have a lot of different processes to use to print a PDF, most like to use adobe reader, and like I said some don't like it. You'll have to find out what the string/command is for that particular process for the legal/landscape.

Although if you want adobe, here's some info for your answer: [link](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Microsoft_Development/Q_26704151.html)

Comment: I am printing a PDF so I do not think that would work, check updated post.

Comment: How would I turn a report viewer into a doc though, current code from MSDN does not work with DOC type

Comment: You aren't turning adobe into a doc, you're turning the pdf into a doc. I think you have a fundamental understanding of what's happening here. But, like I said, there's a link there on how to print using adobe using processes. Or, you could just google how to do it like in here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?670781-Printing-pdf-documents-from-vb-2010 You need to focus on your question you asked here. You said orientation.

Comment: Check the update and you'll understand what I am trying to do, basically I have a ReportViewer and I want to print it without pressing any sort of button, just want to print it on the default printer once it loads.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use 
[gsView](https://netchallenge.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/silent-printing-pdf-in-net-using-gsprint-and-additional-truetype-fonts/)

with postscript. I tryed with adobe reader but with it's not legal on a server and it is not reliable on massive printings. You can change the orientation in the command parameters.